# I keep getting error: cannot find symbol when I compile my code

Tags: java

When I run my code I get "error: cannot find symbol" when it gets to
`tile = board.get(col-1); //get tile`.

I've tried taking the board arraylist out of the constructor, but then I get *error: < identifier > expected* when it get's to `board = b.getBoard();`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm terrible at coding so any help is really appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *The game class holds data about the game
 */
public class Game
{
   private int row; //row
   private int col; //columb

   //create array list of rows 
   ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();

   //create array list of columbs 
   ArrayList<Integer> columbs = new ArrayList<>();

   //create array list of selected tiles 
   ArrayList<Tile> selected = new ArrayList<>();

   private int index = 0; //set index to 0

   /**
      This constructor sets up a game board
   */

   public Game()
   {
      //create new Board
      Board b = new Board();

      //create array list tiles of type Tile 
      ArrayList<Tile> board = new ArrayList<>();

      //call Board's getBoard method
      board = b.getBoard();
   }

   /**
      This constructor sets columb and row variabules
   */

   public Game(int r, int c)
   {
      row = r; //row of tile being tested
      col = c; //columb of tile being tested
   }

   /**
      isValidSelection method  takes the columb and row of
      a tile and returns a boolean value for if the tile is 
      adjacent to the previous tile or not 
      @param the row of the tile
      @param the columb of the tile  
      @return true if tile is adjacent t previous tile
   */

   public boolean isValidSelection(int row, int col)
   {   
      //check if array is empty (no previous tile) 
      if (rows.isEmpty())
      {
         rows.add(row); //add to rows array
         columbs.add(col); //add to columbs array
         return true; //return that tile is adjacent
      }
      else
      {
         //check if tile is adjacent to previous
         if (Math.abs(rows.get(index)-row)<=1)
         {
            rows.add(row); //add to rows array
            columbs.add(col); //add to columbs array
            return true; //return that tile is adjacent
         }
         //check if tile is adjacent to previous
         else if (Math.abs(columbs.get(index)-col)<=1)
         {
            rows.add(row); //add to rows array
            columbs.add(col); //add to columbs array
            return true; //return that tile is adjacent
         }
         //case if tile is not adjacent
         else
         {
            return false; //return that tiles aren't adjacent
         }
      }

      index += 1; //add 1 to index      

   }

   /**
      addToSelected method takes the columb and row of a
      tile and adds them to array of selected tile row and col
      @param the row of the tile
      @param the columb of the tile  
   */

   public void addToSelected(int row, int col)
   { 
      if (row == 1)
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col-1);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
      else if (row == 2)
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col+3);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
      else if (row == 3)
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col+7);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
      else
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col+11);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
   }

   /**
      removeFromSelected method takes the columb and row of a tile 
      and deletes them from array of selected tile row and col
      @param the row of the tile
      @param the columb of the tile  
   */

   public void removeFromSelected(int row, int col)
   { 
      if (row == 1)
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col-1);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
      else if (row == 2)
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col+3);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
      else if (row == 3)
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col+7);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
      else
      {
         Tile tile; //tile
         tile = board.get(col+11);//get tile
         selected.add(tile); // add to selected
      }
   }      
   /**
      toString method
      @return A string containing the board
   */

   public String toString()
   {
      // Create a string representing the board
      String str = board.get(0) + board.get(1) +
                   board.get(2) + board.get(3) + "\n"+
                   board.get(4) + board.get(5) +
                   board.get(6) + board.get(7) + "\n"+
                   board.get(8) + board.get(9) +
                   board.get(10) + board.get(11) + "\n"+
                   board.get(12) + board.get(13) +
                   board.get(14) + board.get(15);

      //return the string
      return str;
   }
}









import java.util.ArrayList; 

import java.util.Scanner; 



public class BoggleText { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // create game 

        Game g = new Game(); 



        // create scanner for user input 

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 



        // variables for user input 

        int row, col; 

        String input; 



        // create flag to end game 

        boolean stop = false; 



        while (!stop) { 

            // print board 

            System.out.println(g); 



            // prompt user for choices 

            System.out.print("(s)elect, (d)eselect, (l)ist selected, " +  
                             "(c)lear  selected, (t)est selected, (e)nd: "); 



            // get choice 

            input = keyboard.nextLine(); 



            // select 

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) { 

                // prompt for row & column 

                System.out.print("row / column [r c]: "); 



                // get row, col from input 

                row = keyboard.nextInt(); 

                col = keyboard.nextInt(); 

                input = keyboard.nextLine(); // clr new line left in buffer 



                // test if the r/c combination is a valid move 

                if (g.isValidSelection(row, col)){ 

                    // add tile to selected tiles 

                    g.addToSelected(row, col); 

                } 

                else { 

                    System.out.println("Invalid selection! Please select " + 
                        "a letter adjacent to the previously " +  
                        "selected letter."); 

                } 

            } 

            // deselect 

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) { 

                // prompt for row & column 

                System.out.print("row / column [r c]: "); 



                // get row, col from input 

                row = keyboard.nextInt(); 

                col = keyboard.nextInt(); 

                input = keyboard.nextLine(); // clr new line left in buffer 



                // remove tile from selected tiles 

                g.removeFromSelected(row,col); 

            } 

            // list currently selected tiles 

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) { 

                ArrayList<Tile> selected = g.getSelectedTiles(); 

                System.out.println(selected); 

            } 



            // clear currently selected tiles 

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) { 

                g.clearSelected(); 

            } 

            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) { 

                g.testSelected(); 

            } 

            // end game 

           else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) { 

                stop = true; 

           }  

         } 

    } 

}
```

I haven't finished writing out game class, but boggletext should be right

Comment: What you're encountering is a scope issue. Your board is only visible within the constructor. You should declare `ArrayList<Tile> board` as a field and not an instance variable. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Comment: @Compass, did you mean as a field and not a *local* variable?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Probably! My terminology stuck in cloud migration at the moment and I'm starting to mix up my languages.

Answer (score -1):

It is exactly like Compass says. If you want to access your variable Board 'b', you should define Board b outside constructor, and then initialize inside your constructor.

```
public class Game{
 ...
 private Board b;
 ...
 public Game(){
    b = new Board();
    ...
 }

}
```

Comment: I did this but I still get the same error

Comment: Since the problem was with the variable `board`, the variable `b` which is only used to create the `board` can remain as a local variable. It's `board` that should be made into an instance variable.